# 400 error using toolbar

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke, http-status-code-400, 2sxc

I have a question about the 2sxc module.

I made a view with the following code:

```
<div class="animated fadeInUp">
<div class="about_team">
<div class="pe-spacer size40"></div>
<ul class="row list-unstyled">

    @foreach(var Content in AsDynamic(Data["Default"])){
        <li class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="state-wrapper" style="height: 231px;"> <img alt="" src="/portals/2/Afbeeldingen/personen/noord-holland%20noord/person.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
            <div class="state-info"> <a href="/Noord-Holland-Noord/Ahmet-Boz">
            <div class="state-circle"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span></div>
            </a> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="team_content">
            <h4>@Content.Naam</h4>
            <p style="font-size: x-small;">@Content.Beroep</p>
            <div class="team_icon clearafter">
            <div class="team_link"> <a href="/Noord-Holland-Noord/Ahmet-Boz" class="more_icon">&rarr;&nbsp;Meer informatie</a> </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        @Edit.Toolbar(Content)
    }
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Which is resulting in this:

[image]

For some reason, I am getting this error when using anything in the toolbar:

[image]

I went to the logs to see if there was any more information:
[image]

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To give you more context - apparently it's failing to "close and finalize" the view-selector - that's the thing above your template. This must happen before it allows you to do any further actions. So you'll probably also get the same error just pressing the blue "check" in the bar above.

Comment: To help a bit more, please tell us what dnn you're using and what 2sxc. + maybe just start anew, add a dnn-module, select your template, might already fix it.